# On click on parent affect child also

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/dialog"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:onclick="hello"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFEE"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/ll">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/title"/>

</LinearLayout>
 <RelativeLayout>
```

However when I click on LinearLayout the function hello is called.
I want function hello should not be called when I click LinearLayout
any suggestion??

Comment: Show your code where you are accessing the id

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how accurate will be.

```
        @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics mertrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);

    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpHeight = metrics.heightPixels / density;
                float y = (float)event.getY();  
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                         if(y < dpHeight / 2 + 50 && y > dpHeight / 2 - 50){
    //no hello() here
    }
else
{
            // call hello() here and remove it from layout
        }
                }
            return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You put `android:onclick="hello"` in wrong place. Try this code and let me know the result

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onclick="hello"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFEE"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/ll">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"        
            android:id="@+id/title"/>
     </LinearLayout>
 <RelativeLayout>
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Hello Thanks. I understand your point. But see, I want my whole application should to respond to hello function except the linear layout and its child. hello function in Relative layout is working good. I just don want it to react when I click on linearlayout

Comment: @Govind It is simple, please set `clickable="false"` in LinearLayout attribute